# How to inspect the variable passed to a function in python

Tags: python, inspect

I have a function receiving some parameters and within the function I want to be able to access these parameters without having to do it by name. Basically I want to be able to get a list of all these parameters and then obtain the values they were bound to when the function was called.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
def myfunc(param1=[], param2=[], param3=[], param4=[]):
    for param in param_list:
        if param.value:
            # do something only if the parameter was actually given by the caller
```

Comment: A pseudo example and its expected outcome would help illustrate what you want here. As is this makes little sense. And the answer is probably `*args, **kwargs`.

Comment: thanks @deceze I have added an example clarifying my intent.

Comment: Using a list as a default parameter value is a bad idea: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/

Comment: If all you want to do is find out whether it's the default or not, why do you need to know what they were named by the caller? You should use e.g. `param1=None` and then check `if param is None: ...`. I think you're solving completely the wrong problem (and making it much harder to test into the bargain).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I actually wanted to avoid writing the same `if` check for each parameter the function accepts. I wanted to be able to get the list of arguments the function declares and then work through it.

Comment: @KristofClaes point taken about using `None` instead of `[]`, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
def my_func(*args, **kwargs):
    for a in args:
        print a
    for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
        print "%s : %s" % (k ,v)
```

Output of `my_func(1, 2, 3)`

```
1
2
3
```

Output of `my_func(1, 2, 3, test=4)`

```
1
2
3
test : 4
```

Comment: although this is working, I think the OP would rather leave the signature as it is, naming the parameters, given his solution. Mind you, it was not specified in the question

Comment: thanks @kristof-claes for your answer. My question was rather unclear and I have added an example to it to make it clearer. Your answer is valid to the extent that you use *args and **kwargs but in my case I wanted to keep the argument names in the function definition.

Comment: @jc.That's what [kwargs](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-can-i-pass-optional-or-keyword-parameters-from-one-function-to-another) is for. ``kwargs[param]`` gives you the argument named ``param``.

Comment: @jc. Sure you're not better served with `**kwargs` and a docstring defining the parameters? As far as Python is concerned those are identical, and defining the parameters in the signature is only useful for tools which do type hinting, which will typically also honour docstrings.

Answer (score 0):

The [inspect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html?highlight=inspect#module-inspect) module provides functions allowing you to inspect the current frame and extract information from it.

```
import inspect

def myfunc(a, b, c, d):

    f = inspect.currentframe()
    v = inspect.getargvalues(f)

    for arg in v.args:
        var_value = v.locals[arg]
        if var_value:
            print arg, '=> ', var_value
```